# Can I apply for business (or other) Visa just to travel for extended time?

Tags: visas, china

For most countries, you can only enter a country without visa for a limited amount of time. In most cases this is 90 days (at least for citizens in developed countries) but sometimes it is only 30 days, or even 15 days.

In these countries, usually there are business or other visas available.

Can I apply for these visas just to travel for extended amount of time

I won't earn any salary from any person or organization within the country, although my job is sole-proprietor iOS Developer and thus I keep gaining revenue just as I do from anywhere in the world.

If more specific details are required, I assume the case of single Japanese people going into China, which lets you only 15 days of visa-free entry. I want to stay there for 30 days to up to 90 days. But I want to get more general answers, if possible.

Comment: "Maybe using a fake contract or certificate?"  It depends, are you looking to spend an extended amount of time in a Chinese prison?  That's visa fraud.  This site won't answer questions on how to break the law and/or get away with it.

Comment: But such countries will typically also offer tourist visas for longer periods of time than the visa-free entry.  Why not just apply for that?

Comment: @NateEldredge Sorry I didn't know it is break the law, as I know several agents that offer fake hotel reservations for those traveling to Russia. Edited.

Comment: @NateEldredge I didn't know such visas exist, and while [it seems that it exists](https://www.travelchinaguide.com/embassy/japan.htm), I couldn't find any page on the embassy of China in Japan that explains it. In fact it didn't exist and that's why I posted the question. I think I must go to the embassy just to hear it, which is ridiculous. But such an onerous task is never uncommon in Japan. It is too ridiculous that it is easier to know it in English than in Japanese, sigh...

Comment: Most countries limit temporary visitors for business to the same duration of stay as temporary visitors for pleasure. In cases where the visa-free stay is 15 or 30 days, one can get a visa for a longer stay regardless of whether the purpose is work or tourism.

Comment: @NateEldredge: It's pretty hard to know what a given country might actually count as visa fraud. Consider things such as purchasing LOI's; or submitting flight tickets, hotel bookings, and itineraries that are required in order to obtain visas in some countries but advice is routinely handed out to cancel the tickets and bookings and ignore the itinerary once you have the visa. We have questions on these topics here. Are they visa fraud? Nobody seemed to say so for those. How is an average person to know the difference between those topics and this one?

Comment: I don't know about most countries. The only countries I've considered getting a business visa for are Russia, because you can apparently travel more freely regarding things such as registering. This just requires a different kind of ROI that a tourist visa, and agencies will sell you either ROI. The other country I know about is Cambodia, where a business visa can be obtained at the border for $5 more than a tourist visa but you can pay at an immigration office to extend it for up to one year, which you cannot do with a tourist visa. Who knows what other countries' business visas might entail?

Answer (score 2):

For starters obtaining a visa under false pretenses is grounds for arrest once you are in the country, fines and deportation.  It is far better to obtain a tourist visa for as long of period as offered, then limit your travels to that length of time.

But addressing the visa differences ... most non tourist visa types require documentation appropriate to your visit.  A family visit or marriage visa requires proof of relations (marriage licenses, birth certificate, etc).  A business visa requires proof of business contacts, usually in the form of letter of invitations from registered companies (some of the business visas I currently hold require not only a letter, but copies of that company's registration papers). So obtaining a visa like this is not an easy alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it isn't legal, and not even the best way to do things, and might get denied anyways.

It isn't that hard (for US citizens) to get a 6-month multi-entry tourist visa for China. And if you want to stay longer, it is easy to go for a day trip to Japan, South Korea, or Hong Kong every 5.5 months. I think it is even possible that the local police can update your visa for you to extend your stay, depending on where you are and what your justification is.

So it really makes more sense to follow the rules in this case.

Comment: I would not state that first paragraph as you do, a careless reader could interpret it wrongly. Regarding your second paragraph, not all of us are US citizens (and the OP never saif so AFAIK). Also they [only get 60 days of stay on each entry](http://www.mychinavisa.com/china-visa-faq/). I agree with your last sentence!